# A way to get at non-static information from Static Context

Tags: c#

I know you can't static members from instance members.

But lets say I have in one assembly this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public List<order> GetOrders(int orderID)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in another assembly this:

```
public static ClassB
{
    private static void DoSomethingElse(int orderID)
    {
        List<order> orderList = ClassA.GetOrders(orderID);
        ...rest of code
    }
}
```

Is there any way to still get at that method in Class A some other way...some work around to this?

Comment: You'll need an instance of `ClassA` in order to call `GetOrders(..)` as it's not marked `static`.  Did you mean it to be `static` instead?

Comment: I guess I could pass the Singleton to the other assembly possibly into that method in ClassB

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Singletons usually provide a way of other classes accessing them: `ClassA.GetInstance()` or whatever.

Comment: It sounds like `ClassA` needs a static `Instance` property, or it needs to have all static members. Otherwise I don't think it constitutes a singleton...

Comment: I can't just change the members to all static in ClassA, that would be a huge refactoring.  I understand what Singletons are, what static vs. instance is.  I just wondered if there was any way around this besides just changing a member to me the same type (static or instance).  Looks like no work arounds here.

Comment: Sorry all it's been a long day and I just totally termed the question wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You certainly *can* access static members from instance members... but you should understand *why* you can't access instance members without an instance.

Your class basically says that each instance of `ClassA` allows you to get a list of orders associated with a particular ID. Now, different instances of `ClassA` might give different results - for example, they might be connecting to different databases. Which results do you want to get in `DoSomethingElse`?

To give a simpler example, suppose we had a `Person` class, and each person had a name:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Does it make sense to ask "What is `Person.Name`?" No - because you haven't specified which person you're talking about.

You should either make `ClassA.GetOrders` static - if it doesn't involve any per-instance information, including virtual members - or make `ClassB` aware of the instance of `ClassA` to use when finding out the orders.

If you could let us know more realistic names for these classes, we could give guidance as to which solution is more likely to be appropriate... personally I would *generally* favour the latter approach, as static members generally lead to less testable code.

Comment: I'm talking about accessing non-static members through static members...the other way around which is not possible.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: "non-static" = "instance". My first sentence is a response to *your* first sentence: "I know you can't access static members from instance members and vice versa." That's just wrong.

Comment: Yea I understand all this. I guess I just wondered if there was some alternative to get around this issue.  I don't want to change ClassA to be static or vice versa..I'd have a huge refactoring issue.

Comment: @coffeeaddict: I wasn't suggesting that ClassA itself should be static - but *either* GetOrders needs to be static *or* you need to make an instance of ClassA available. How could there be any alternative to those options?

Comment: Jon, just got your book, LOVE IT!  (C# In Depth)

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Glad to hear it - do feel free to ping me with questions or suggestions. Hope you enjoy the rest!

Comment: There is no alternative, just wondered if someone had a trick up their sleeves.  It's just I did not want to go changing a ton of code as this pile is a huge pile with no structure to it which is why I have this problem in the first place ;).  I'm good.

Comment: The best part of your book so far are delegates.  I'm on that chapter.  Well, it's all been good actually but delegates is my weakness

Answer (score 4):

Not sure I got you right, but try `new ClassA().GetOrder(orderID);`

Answer (score 2):

> I know you can't access static members from instance members and vice versa.

Actually you can.

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static void Foo()
   {
       Console.Write("Foo");
   }

   public void Bar()
   {
       Foo(); // Perfectly valid call
   }
}
```

But to go the other way (instance from static) you need to actually CREATE an instance:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static void Foo()
   {
       MyClass c = new MyClass();
       c.Bar();
   }

   public void Bar()
   {
       Console.Write("Foo");
   }
}
```

You may be confusing `static` with it's meaning in *different languages*. In C# it means that the member is not bound to any specific instance of the class, you could in effect call the static member from the above examples like this:

```
MyClass.Foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the Singleton instance and you don't have a static singleton accessor (such as `.Instance` or `.GetInstance()`), then you can inject the instance into ClassB through some means before calling the method (this example uses a public static field, but you'll want something safer in practice):

```
public static class ClassB
{
    //The single instance has to be injected before DoSomethingElse can be used
    public static ClassA ClassA;

    private static void DoSomethingElse(int orderID)
    {
        List<Order> orderList = ClassA.GetOrders(orderID);
        //...rest of code
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can pass the ClassA instance directly into DoSomethingElse.  Since ClassB depends on ClassA, it might make more sense for ClassB to be a singleton-style service as well, which allows you to inject ClassA's instance via the constructor (perhaps automatically with some IoC framework).